# JQuery FormData in IE - changing to JQuery Form plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which has a lot of inputs including two file upload fields.  I had everything working with FormData but I have since come to realise that
this does not work in IE8 or IE9 (and I need it too).  As such, I am probably going to switch and use the [JQuery Form](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/jquery-form-plugin-and-php-file-uploads/) plugin instead.

I wont show the html form because it is a lot of code, but its just a simple form with a lot of fields really.  What I do first is some validation using the [JQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin.  As you can see below, all the FormData stuff is done in the submitHandler.

```
$(function () {
    var validator = $("#my-form").validate({
        errorContainer: "#validation-results",
        errorLabelContainer: "#validation-results",
        errorElement: "li",
        groups: {
            fileGroup: "fileOne fileTwo"
        },
        rules: {
            //All the appropriate rules
        },
        messages: {
            //All the appropriate messages
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            formData   = new FormData(),
            params     = $(form).serializeArray(),
            fileOne    = $(form).find('[name="fileOne"]')[0].files,
            fileTwo    = $(form).find('[name="fileTwo"]')[0].files;

            if(fileOne.length != 0) {
                $.each(fileOne, function(i, file) {
                    formData.append('fileOne-' + i, file);
                });
            }

            if(fileTwo.length != 0) {
                $.each(fileTwo, function(i, file) {
                    formData.append('fileTwo-' + i, file);
                });
            }

            $.each(params, function(i, val) {
                formData.append(val.name, val.value);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/process.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            }).done(function (response) {

            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

My main question is how can I integrate the JQuery Form Plugin with the JQuery Validate code above?  I presume I use the submitHandler above, but is it just a case of adding the following
to replicate what I currently have in my submitHandler?

```
$("#my-form").ajaxSubmit(); 
return false;
```

Any advice on how to combine the two would be great.  My main aim is to get this working properly in IE.

Many thanks

Comment: FormData api won't work on some IE older ones.

Comment: I know, that is why I posted the question